# Multiple Access token for a single api endpoint

Tags: http-headers, jwt, okta

Is it possible to send multiple access token via form encoded parmeter or multiple authorization header of type bearer token parameter to an api?

Comment: It's possible in that you could write the code to do it on your client. On the server, you'd probably have to write custom logic that splits the header into separate JWTs and then validates them individually. I'm curious, why do you want to do this?

Comment: I actually want to send a user token and a client token containing different scopes.